# List total free space in available drives VB.net

Tags: diskspace

I am trying to get the free disk space from all the logical drives available on the computer using batch and VB.net. Using "wmic" i get the required output and then using VB convert the 'bytes' value to MB/GB/KB but the problem is i am unable to get the VB script to read the text  output from 'wmic' command. Below is the 'wmic' code.

```
wmic LogicalDisk Where DriveType="3" Get DeviceID,FreeSpace > Diskspace.txt
```

Below the vb code to read the 'diskspace.txt' file

```
Set objFSO = CreateObject ("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile ("diskspace.txt",1)
Contents = objFile.Readall
objFile.close
```

The point being is there a simpler way to get available free space from all the logical drives on the system ? or i am doing something wrong in my above code.

I also tried "/format:csv" parameter in wmic, but not able to get it to read in VB.

Answer (score 0):

Found the Solution !!

The output of a WMI is on unicode format and needs to be converted to ASCII format for VB to be able to read it.

To convert use the TYPE command (batch) as below

```
TYPE diskspace.txt > NEWdiskspace.txt
```